Spring WS - Soap request is missing header
I am using SpringBoot SOAP web service (spring-boot-starter-web-services).
I configured Jaxb2Marshaller and WebServiceGatewaySupport beans. The problem is, that the produced soap request is:

missing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" header
The name space url is incorrect: instead of xmlns:SOAP-ENV="/soap-envelope" i need "/soapenvelope"

How to change schema name and add the required xml header?
I tried to configure JAXB2Marshaller
